# Uniform Convergence of $\frac{2x}{1+x^2}+\frac{4x^3}{1+x^4}+\frac{8x^7}{1+x^8}+...$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, uniform-convergence

Show that following series is uniformly convergent in $(-1,1)$.

$$\frac{2x}{1+x^2}+\frac{4x^3}{1+x^4}+\frac{8x^7}{1+x^8}+...$$

I had previously solved this problem using Weierstrass M test by taking 
$$|f_n| = |\frac{2^n.x^{2^n-1}}{1+x^{2^n}}| \leq 2^n.k^{2^n-1}, k\in(x,1)$$

Thus, $\frac{M_n}{M_{n+1}}\to \infty$ hence the series is uniformly convergent. But now I think this is incorrect as $k$ shouldn't be dependent on $x$. How should I proceed then?

Comment: Are you sure it is uniformly convergent on all of $(-1,1)$? On any $[-a,a]$, $0<a<1,$ for sure, but on the whole interval?

Comment: I mean, the individual terms grow without a bound, so the series cannot converge uniformly!

Comment: [Here](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/bobefm64xf) is a visualisation of the behaviour of your function.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The series $\sum \frac{2^n.x^{2^n-1}}{1+x^{2^n}}$ is not uniformly convergent on $(-1,1)$. If it was $v_n = \sup\limits_{x \in (-1,1)} \left\vert \frac{2^n.x^{2^n-1}}{1+x^{2^n}} \right\vert$ would be such that $v_n \to 0$.

But

$$\left\vert \frac{2^n.x^{2^n-1}}{1+x^{2^n}} \right\vert \ge 2^{n-1} \vert x \vert^{2^n-1}$$ and the right hand side of the inequality is unbounded in $(-1,1)$.

Comment: mathcounterexample. Please elaborate. Not uniformly continuos. If it was then v_n =sup (..) to zero for n to infty. You show that the(sufficient) Weierstrass test is not applicable? Thanks.

Comment: If a sequence of functions $(f_n)$ converges uniformly to $f$, then $(f_{n+1}-f_n)$ converges uniformly to zero. Applying that to the partial sums of the series of functions, you get the result.

Comment: mathcounterexample.Thanks.

Comment: @mathcounterexamples.net can u please explain how do you get the inequality?